# Force an image to fit and keep aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I want an image to fill the 100% of its container's width, and I want it to have a max-heigth property set to it, all this keeping the aspect ratio but allowing to lose any part of the image.

```
img {
   max-height:200px;
   width:100%;
}
```

I know a similar thing can be done with `background-size` property but i want to make this to an inline `<img>` tag.

Any idea of how could i achieve this using CSS? or javascript?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can try CSS3 **[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)**, and see browser support **[tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)**.

> CSS3 `object-fit`/`object-position` Method of specifying how an object (image or video) should fit inside
> its box. object-fit options include "contain" (fit according to aspect
> ratio), "fill" (stretches object to fill) and "cover" (overflows box
> but maintains ratio), where object-position allows the object to be
> repositioned like background-image does.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k7h1xvr7/)**</kbd>

```css
.container-1 {
  width: 150px; /*any size*/
  height: 150px; /*any size*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container-2 {
  width: 300px; /*any size*/
  height: 150px; /*any size*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.object-fit-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /*magic*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <img class="object-fit-cover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg">
</div>

<br>

<div class="container-2">
  <img class="object-fit-cover" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3pb.jpg">
</div>
```

---

**Related Info:**

- [Exploring object-fit ★ Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/02/exploring-object-fit/)
- [Polyfill for CSS object-fit property](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit)

Comment: the example could be improved by showing what happens if you change the width of the container

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I updated the demos with different container sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using css flex properties. Please see the code below

```css
.img-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.img-container .img-to-fit {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="img-to-fit" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8633/nature-tree-green-pine.jpg" />
</div>
```