# Keep aspect ratio of dynamically loaded image

Tags: css

On my website, users can upload pictures. They can be of various sizes, but I want them to fit in boxes of the same height, so they can be put next to each other and form a grid. The image should be centered in the box, keeping it's aspect ratio. Can I do this in CSS? I've been trying things with flexbox, but I can't make it work.

e.g.

If height is larger than width:

```
|-------------| 
|   imageim   |
|   ageimag   |
|   eimagei   |
|   mageima   |
|   geimage   |
|   imageim   |
|-------------|
```

If width is larger than height:

```
|-------------|
|             |
|imageimageima|
|geimageimagei|
|mageimageimag|
|eimageimageim|
|             |
|-------------|
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. Maybe it's because the height and width of my containing div is set to 100%, instead of a fixed value?

Comment: See this post and answer if that helps - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34713763/483779 but be aware of the browser support details.

Comment: Posted an answer for you, though to understand better what you look for, a picture showing an expected layout with a mix of image sizes would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 5 x 5 grid, scaling, downloadable, using `flex`.

[Fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/udf8Lr6m/2/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: calc(20% - 2px);
  width: calc(20% - 2px);
  background: #ddd no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 1px;
}
.parent a:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3);
}
.parent a:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>

  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>  

  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>  

  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>  

  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/animals/3" download="filename"></a>
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/150/300/animals/3" download="filename"></a>  

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is one downside to your solution. The images can't be downloaded. The section of the site will function as a kind of photo book, so it would be nice if users could download the pictures. Also, I would like the pictures to scale with the surrounding div, so the width and height should be expressed in % instead of pixels. I'm trying to make a grid with 5 columns and 5 rows. I could try to do it in JavaScript, but I would like to know first whether there is a css solution, maybe using the new layouts like flexbox (of which I don't know much).

Comment: @raichu Updated my answer with a suggestion

Comment: Thank you! Awesome. I've been fiddling around with flexboxes the whole afternoon.:)

Answer (score -2):

```
height: 100px;
width: auto;
```

This will resize the images to fit that height.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this only works in one situation: when the image is oriented vertically. But people should also be able to post horizontally oriented pictures.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work then? It will scale the images irrespective of their dimensions. Horizontal or vertical. You can add a text-align center to the parent of you want to align them to center. Or do you also want to box to be of a fixed width as well? In that case put a max-width: 100px on it.

Comment: The box shouldn't be fixed width, but a percentage of it's parent. The goal is to create a grid for a user's images.

Comment: Yeah that and a justify-content: space-around on parent flex box is what I use for doing exactly that.