# Setting a boundary for an image without changing the image's original ratio

Tags: html, css, image

I have a tricky question which i couldn't find any solution online. (All solutions didn't do what i need.)

I have a div with the following css:

```
.logo {
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;//translates into 460px
    width: 32%;//translates into 240px
}
```

Inside there is a single  element with an unknown ratio which changes from image to image. (One image can be 400x200, the other one can be 100x100, the 3rd one can be 300x100 etc... i don't really know the height and width of the image in advanced)

The goal:
I want to show the image while using the maximum size possible of the parent div, without changing the image's aspect ration.

Comment: is `.logo` the class of the image or it's container?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you want to do, but did you try setting max-width: 100% and max-height: 100%, width and height to auto on the image inside the div?

Comment: Or use is a background image and set it background-size: contain: https://jsfiddle.net/3aw4jtzj/ that will make the image as big as possible while keeping the right aspect ratio. Depends on your use-case.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pr2L3agr/ this may be helpful

Comment: `.logo` is the class of the container @Scott

Comment: @deadfishli yes i did. I'm testing on chrome and it doesn't seem like Chrome react to width:auto;height:auto

Comment: I wonder if this is what you're looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34713763/483779

Comment: What you gave is utterly insufficient to reproduce the issue. We could provide solutions, but unless you reveal more of the markup structure, they're not guaranteed to work. The most important part here is the relation between `.logo` and its immediate parent. Note whenever you're mixing `float`s with `flex` you're in for headaches.

Comment: `//`is javascript comment, not CSS ... so whatever rule is next is ignored because of a funny syntaxe ....    float on itself is fine height or width: XX% need a value in parent to be calculated, vh and vw can avoid it , also an extra flex container for eah image maybe ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLpeXR