# Restricting slideshow images to height/width of the slideshow container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a modal image, that when clicked on open a slideshow, with a prev, and next button that are aligned halfway down from the top of the slideshow. When an image is longer than the slideshow container the slideshow becomes longer, rather than the image becoming smaller to fit the slideshow container (but stay centered).

I want it so that the container always stays the same size, and if the image is shorter, then I'd rather it be centered than moving up as it does now. (basically I want the next, and prev buttons to always in the same position, and halfway down the image). I've been stuck on this for a while, and 
I've tried some stuff but none of it seems to work.

Note: the 1200x800 image is my standard for what I'd kind of like it to be like, the first pic is an example of too short, last is an example of too long.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE][1]

HTML:

```
<body>

  <h2 style="text-align:center">Modal Albums</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://chasingseals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/greenlandBanner2000x800.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.catholicevangelism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/1200x800.gif" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="http://www.a1carpet-to.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/600x400.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://support.kickofflabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/800x1200.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
 }

 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .row > .column {
   padding: 0 8px;
 }

 .row:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
 }

 .column {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
 }
 /* The Modal (background) */

 .modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 }
 /* Modal Content */

 .modal-content {
   position: relative;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0;
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1200px;
 }
 /* The Close Button */

 .close {
   color: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   right: 25px;
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }

 .close:hover,
 .close:focus {
   color: #999;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .mySlides {
   display: none;
 }

 .cursor {
   cursor: pointer
 }
 /* Next & previous buttons */

 .prev,
 .next {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: auto;
   padding: 16px;
   margin-top: -50px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 20px;
   transition: 0.6s ease;
   border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
   user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
 }
 /* Position the "next button" to the right */

 .next {
   right: 0;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 }
 /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

 .prev:hover,
 .next:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 /* Number text (1/3 etc) */

 .numbertext {
   color: #f2f2f2;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
 }

 img {
   margin-bottom: -4px;
 }

 t img.hover-shadow {
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 }

 .hover-shadow:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1);
 }

 .modal-content {
   -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
   animation-name: zoom;
   animation-duration: 0.6s;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
   from {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0)
   }
   to {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1)
   }
 }

 @keyframes zoom {
   from {
     transform: scale(0)
   }
   to {
     transform: scale(1)
   }
 }
```

JS:

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

EDIT:

![What i want it to look like]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFAYg.jpg
the shaded in part is the actual image, the box I've drawn is the container (which ofc isn't actually visible on the page)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following CSS this should fix your issue.
I am not sure I understand exactly how you want things to scale.

After your comment I Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713763/force-an-image-to-fit-and-keep-aspect-ratio) that may help you using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

You will need to define a height for your container in this case I set it to 200px but you can pick whatever works best for you.

```
.mySlides {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
.mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/nhk3o0m1/2/)

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 // var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  /*for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }*/
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  //dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  //captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row>.column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

t img.hover-shadow {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.modal-content {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
.mySlides {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
.mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Modal Albums</h2>
<span ></span>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal ">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content ">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://chasingseals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/greenlandBanner2000x800.jpg" >
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.catholicevangelism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/1200x800.gif" >
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.a1carpet-to.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/600x400.png" >
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://support.kickofflabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/800x1200.png" >
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it so that the slideshow always stays in the center of the page, and like if the image is too wide, then it shrinks and theres now room on the top and bottom. If it is too long then it shrinks and now theres room on the sides. Would this solution you suggested still work if I used vh and vw so that the slideshow stays the same relative to the window size

Comment: try it. what happens?

Comment: No it doesn't, also I want the images to maintain their original aspect ratio when they shrink.

Comment: I've made an edit to hopefully clarify what I want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Change your img style to ( style ="width:1900px;height:970px" align="middle" )

Example

```
<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
<img src="http://chasingseals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/greenlandBanner2000x800.jpg"  style ="width:1900px;height:970px" align="middle" >
</div>
```

And you need to do some changes in CSS too.

Comment: I suggest you read this document: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks It will help make your answers more readable and thus more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Change this in your HTML file ,

```
    <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="http://chasingseals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/greenlandBanner2000x800.jpg"  style ="width:1900px;height:970px" align="middle" >
    </div>
```