# Filling a div with an image tag is not working when a large max-height is set

Tags: css

I am trying to get a `<img>` to expand to fill the height of its parent, using `max-height`. This image will act as a banner image.

My problem is that if a larger height is set, the image does not fill it completely, maintaining its aspect ratio.

https://jsfiddle.net/f5bpz16r/2/

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav {
  width: 155px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  border-left: 1px solid #000
}

  nav > .nav-area {
    width: 155px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }

    nav > .nav-area > a.logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 15px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      height: 80px;
      width: 187px;
    }

.wrap {
  margin-right: 155px;
}

.wrap .inner-wrap {
    padding: 45px 55px 0 55px
}

header > .small, 
header > .medium,
header > .large, 
header > .x-large {
  overflow:hidden
}

header img {
  width:100%
}

header > .small {
  max-height: 377px
}

header > .medium {
  max-height: 532px
}

header > .large {
  max-height: 884px
}

header > .x-large {
  max-height: 1082px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-area">
        <a class="logo" href="/">
     LOGO
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
        <div class="wrap">
            <header>
                <div class="large">
                    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/461775/pexels-photo-461775.jpeg" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="inner-wrap">
                    Wrap
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `<img`> is plenty big enough. At 4000px high.

Comment: Probably the same as this [Force an image to fit and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713763/483779)

Comment: @Pangloss object-fit has bad support across browsers does it not?

Comment: Well, yes if you care about IE, your have other options like using JS or background image.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that there are always a few pixels below the image, it is because images have a display property of `inline` by default. Change it to `block`:

```
header img {
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
```

The height of `inline` elements is affected by the line-height, which accounts for text with descending characters, like 'p', 'j', 'q', etc.

If what you want is to make the image take as much space as allowed by it container you could use

```
header img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

However I think you would have more control by using the image as a background-image on the header. Then you could use the [`background-size` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images).

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid this has no change.

Comment: I was not sure whether this was actually your problem... So what you want it for the image to fill up the header?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps

```
<img style="display:block; height:100%">
```