# Img height on auto height div

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ry9gyb8n/

Hi guys , I have been trying to solve this problem since a couple of weeks.
I have an auto height container , the left div in the container is auto height as it can have various different content inside it.
The right div will always have an image but I dont know the height of the image.

How do I make it so the image doesnt exceed the height of the content on the left?

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.leftContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.rightContainer {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg/1200px-London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Give the image same height as text in left container?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what Im trying to do , however the problem is the text in the left container can be variable in terms of height.

Comment: Cool I just posted your answer. :)

Comment: Isn’t it possible for you to use it as a sort of background of the div.. and control the position and size through the additional settings in the background property

Comment: You might be looking for object-fit, https://jsfiddle.net/k23xtpha/ with position tricks, here https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713763/483779 for more about it.

Comment: A problem with object-fit , same as background-img solutions is that if the img is small then the img will get stretched for example : https://jsfiddle.net/k23xtpha/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with flex to create the layout and make the image out of the flow using absolute position so it won't give its container a height and thus the height will be equal to the left one. Then simply adjust the properties of the image to make it fit the container as you need:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.leftContainer {
  flex:1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.rightContainer {
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  max-height:100%; /* Or height:100%*/
  max-width:100%;
  /*to center the image if needed*/
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  /**/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightContainer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg/1200px-London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to use the same layout as above and make the image as background. You will have the same situation because there is no content and thus the height will be the same as the left column. Then adjust the image position/size using background properties:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.leftContainer {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.rightContainer {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg/1200px-London_Bridge_Illuminated.jpg");
  background-size: contain; /* or cover or 100% 100% or auto*/
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightContainer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow on my project and get back to you but your solution looks solid.

Comment: @user9174675 i also added another idea ;)

Comment: I didn't notice that you added flexbox. I deleted my answer. :) the copy paste was not intentional.

Comment: Only problem to the background img solution is if the image is small then it stretches the image out of its original size. For example : https://jsfiddle.net/jh3gymxv/

Comment: @user9174675 not a problem, simply use `auto` with background size when it's small:)

Comment: Hey thanks dude, I will definitely try this tomorrow.

Comment: Ok so I used your first solution and it worked perfectly . I also tried the 2nd solution however It wasnt compatible as the height of my text columns are variable therefore I would have to switch it from contain to auto when the image overflows from the box.