# Flexbox make image resize to match text height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

EDIT:
Here are three screenshots showing what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So basically you can see the braces scale to match the height of the content, which decreases as the browser gets wider. The above is doable with Javascript (which is how I took the screenshots), but I was hoping there was a CSS-only approach to it.
(END EDIT)

I have a 1:2:1 flex horizontal layout where I have a left border image in a div, then some text content in a div, and then a right border image in a div. The border images are usually much taller than the content, and I'm trying to have them shrink down so that their heights always match the height of the text content.

I've tried a variety of things and read through articles where people seem to have the same problem but none of the suggested solutions have worked so far. I've stripped it down to the most basic elements and posted the desired structure here using a stock photo for the border:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
}

.img>img {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='img' style='text-align:right'>
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/stack-of-colorful-books-left-border-picture-id147704087">
  </div>
  <div class='text' style='text-align:center'>
    Hello<br />World!<br />How are you?
  </div>
  <div class='img' style='text-align:left'>
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/stack-of-colorful-books-left-border-picture-id147704087">
  </div>
</div>
```

No matter what I've tried (most of them involving turning off flex-grow, or setting height to either 100% or auto, the image always tries to grow rather than shrinking to match the content, so I end up with grossly-oversized borders.

Comment: instead of using img elements inside divs use css background images for the empty divs maybe?

Comment: I could not get the background approach working correctly - can you post some sample code based on what I have?

Comment: Do you want a flexbox solution or any css solution would be ok ?

Comment: I'd be open to other css solutions

Comment: I know I can probably do this in JavaScript but I'm trying to leave that as a last resort

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612601/img-height-on-auto-height-div/48612679#48612679

Comment: Almost a duplicate, but no. The solution there ends up resizing the image back down after the browser is narrow enough for the image to hit its peak height.

Comment: It would be good to know if the answer helps feel free to comment.

Comment: I had to resort temporarily to the Javascript approach due to deadlines, but I'm planning on testing out this approach as soon as I have an opening.

Comment: No problem and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to do it with flexbox + background images.

- Make a three column layout with flexbox, example uses pseudo elements.
- Use background images for the two quotes, key is `background-size: auto 100%;`

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzwpqQ?editors=1100)**

```css
.quote {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.quote:before,
.quote:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

.quote:before {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDgT.png");
  background-position: right center;
}

.quote:after {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkT0.png");
  background-position: left center;
}

.quote .text {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>

<div class="quote" style="max-width: 400px;">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

Although, you can still use inline images, the key is to set the `img` to `position: absolute;`, so that the container can calculate the height based on the text content.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEdMLa?editors=1100)**

```css
.quote {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.quote .image {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.quote .image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.quote .left img {
  right: 0;
}

.quote .right img {
  left: 0;
}

.quote .text {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <div class="image left">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDgT.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="image right">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkT0.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="quote" style="max-width: 400px;">
  <div class="image left">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDgT.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="image right">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkT0.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using flexbox and with only one div.

Your div will have two background, each will take 25% of the width.

The text will have a width of 50% (100% minus the width of the two backgrounds) and a padding of 25% on the left and on the right.

It will work as long as your background image are longer than the text.

```css
div {
  background: url('http://placeimg.com/400/800/nature'), url('http://placeimg.com/400/800/nature'); /* the two backgrounds */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; /* you don't want them to repeat */ 
  background-size: 25% auto, 25% auto; /* you set them to occupy 25% of the width and to keep the ratio for the height */
  background-position: top left, top right; /* you position on one the left, one on the right */
  width: 50%;
  padding:0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga mollitia libero recusandae aperiam soluta odit, laborum repellendus explicabo nemo, ea accusamus facilis, unde deleniti laudantium possimus repudiandae natus quas officiis.
  </div>
```

Comment: No, that actually cuts off the image. I want the images to scale.

Comment: @jhilgeman Can you be more precise ? Should it keep the ratio ? Should it just shrink ?